# Unable to access ArrayList object method

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program that randomly picks 3 countries from a pool, then outputs them as a string. These countries will receive gold, silver, and bronze in order. The method olympicResults will add each string into an array. Eventually, all the countries will be sorted by the number of gold, silver and bronze medals attained.

I'm having trouble with the eventResult method - I can't seem to access methods from my country class, like getName() - just gives me the cannot find symbol error. It seemed to work before when I initialized the ArrayList in the eventResult method, but that wouldn't work since a new arraylist would be initialized every time the method was called.

Another problem is with preventing repeats of countries appearing in an eventResult string - any ideas of what I did wrong?

Code:

```
public class OlympicMedals 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String[] countries = {"CAN", "BRB", "BLR", "HKG", "CHN", "SWE"}
    ArrayList<Country> list = new ArrayList<Country>();
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++) //initialize countries
    {
        list.add(new Country());
        list.get(j).setName(countries[j]);
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    Print(n, list);

}


public static String eventResult (ArrayList list) //generates result of discipline
{
    String res = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Country> listCopy = new ArrayList<Country>(list); 

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) //generate list, prevent repeats
    {  
        int n = listCopy.size();
        int random = rand.nextInt(n);
        res += list.get(random).getName() + " ";

        if (i==0)
            list.get(random).setGold(1);
        if (i==1)
            list.get(random).setSilver(1);
        if (i==2)
            list.get(random).setBronze(1);

        listCopy.remove(random);
    }
    return res;           
}

public static String[] olympicResults(int n, ArrayList list) //array of strings from eventResult
{
    String[] result;
    result = new String[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        result[i] = eventResult(list);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void Print(int n, ArrayList list)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) //print results
    {
        System.out.println(olympicResults(n, list)[i]);
    }
}
```

Country class:

```
public class Country 
{
private int gold;
private int silver;
private int bronze;
private String name;

public Country() //default constructor
{
    setName("");
    setGold(0);
    setSilver(0);
    setBronze(0);
}

public void setName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setGold(int g)
{
    gold += g;
}

public int getGold()
{
    return gold;
}

public void setSilver(int s)
{
    silver += s;
}

public int getSilver()
{
    return silver;
}

public void setBronze(int b)
{
    bronze += b;
}

public int getBronze()
{
    return bronze;
}
```

}

Comment: You should use generics everywhere, like `eventResult (ArrayList list) ` should be `eventResult (ArrayList<Country> list) `

Comment: Clean up your code first. Has quite a few bugs in it. Both `syntactical` and `logical`.

Comment: @Apurv Oh wow. That fixed it, thanks! Any advice for repeat prevention?

Comment: What do you mean by __preventing repeats of countries appearing in an eventResult string__ ?

Comment: How did `countries[j]` for **6,7,8,9** not give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I'm amazed.

Comment: For example, i'm getting strings like CHN CHN SWE - there shouldn't be two of the same country. I tried making a copy of the ArrayList and removing a country at the end of an iteration after it's been called, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @R.J - Oops. I'm not sure either.. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code changes ?

```
public static String eventResult (ArrayList<Country> list) //generates result of discipline
{
    String res = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Country> listCopy = new ArrayList<Country>(list); 

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)  { 
        int random = rand.nextInt(listCopy.size());
        res += listCopy.get(random).getName() + " ";
        if (i==0)
            listCopy .get(random).setGold(1);
        if (i==1)
            listCopy .get(random).setSilver(1);
        if (i==2)
            listCopy .get(random).setBronze(1);

        listCopy.remove(random); // remove the country which received a medal from the list
    }    
    return res;           
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Not sure how that for loop is supposed to work out. Thanks though, i'll keep trying.